# Android Speech to Text conversion: Android Application is receiving repeated words when spoken through Voice input using Android Virtual keyboard

Tags: android, speech-to-text

Sample Application (Steps):

1. An Android Application without EditText control.
2. The application has an activity that contains a Text View.
3. In the onCreate() method of the Activity, Bring the Virtual 
   Keyboard i.e. SoftKeyBoard when the application 
   is launched.
4. Press on the Mic (Voice input) button of the virtual keyboard.
5. Speak "How are You".

Results of the Voice Input:
Android application receives the above spoken words in three iterations like,
"How"
"are"
"How are you"

which is in-correct. If You see, the words **"How"** and **"are"** is repeated in the third iteration.

Expected Result:
Application should receive the spoken words in three iterations like this
"How"
"are"
"you"

Here is the Sample Application Code:

public class TestSpeechToText extends Activity {

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_test_url);
    /* Default display keyboard */
    this.getWindow().setSoftInputMode(WindowManager.LayoutParams.SOFT_INPUT_STATE_ALWAYS_VISIBLE);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_test_url, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyUp(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int count, KeyEvent event) {
    String text = event.getCharacters();
    Log.d("Testing", "Text is " + event.toString());
    return true;
}
```

}

In this case, overridden method onKeyMultiple() is called thrice, with text as
"How", "are" and "How are you"

Note:
1. There is no EditText control
2. The xml layout contains only a Text View

Is anyone aware of this problem? If yes, How it can be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

If there's no EditText I'd do the Intent calling stuff myself, not via SoftKeyboard. Then you'll get an Array containing all recognized words. Pure and simple.

```
private void startVoiceRecognitionActivity()
{
    Intent intent = new Intent(RecognizerIntent.ACTION_RECOGNIZE_SPEECH);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_LANGUAGE_MODEL,
            RecognizerIntent.LANGUAGE_MODEL_FREE_FORM);
    intent.putExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_PROMPT, "Voice recognition Demo...");
    startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
}

protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
{
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK)
    {
        // Populate the wordsList with the String values the recognition engine thought it heard
        ArrayList<String> matches = data.getStringArrayListExtra(RecognizerIntent.EXTRA_RESULTS);
        // Manipulate your data or do whatever you like with the result
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Powell. I am aware of the above case. 
Thing is, 
I would like to handle it when I press Mic button on virtual    keyboard but Android does not provide mic button detection mechanism i.e. Application does not get Key Event on Mic button press even though app registers for Key Events. So the above    mentioned resolution cannot be used. 
So only way is to override onKeyMultiple() method and get the results. What do You say?

Answer (score 0):

I did a workaround to get individual words and skip the repeated sentence:

```
@Override
public boolean onKeyMultiple(int keyCode, int repeatCount, KeyEvent event) {
    int numOfWords = event.getCharacters().trim().split(" ").length;

    if (numOfWords == 1) {

        // Do your stuff here with event.getCharacters()
    }

    return true;

}
```